# Convert list of strings to dictionary with duplicate keys

Tags: python

I would like to convert a list of strings into dictionary:

```
list1 = ["a:2", "b:5", "c:7", "a:8"]

dict1 = dict(i.split(":", 1) for i in list1)
print(dict1)
```

Expected output:

`{"a":2, "b":5, "c":7, "a":8}`

but the output I got is:
`{"b":5, "c":7, "a":8}`

Can anybody help, please?

Comment: you cannot have duplicate keys in a dict. However you can have some container type as value, e.g. `{"b":5, "c":7, "a":[2, 8]}`

Comment: How to write a script to get that container?

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries can't contain duplicate keys.

Trying your example output in the Python REPL:

```
Python 3.7.3
>>> {"a":2, "b":5, "c":7, "a":8}
{'a': 8, 'b': 5, 'c': 7}
>>>
```

You see the first `a` value is lost.

Comment: Thanks AKX! I truly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will create a dictionary which the values are lists:

```
list1 = ["a:2", "b:5", "c:7", "a:8"]
dic = {}
for item in list1:
    key, value = item.split(":")
    if key not in dic:
        dic[key] = []
    dic[key].append(value)

print(dic)
```

output:

```
{'a': ['2', '8'], 'b': ['5'], 'c': ['7']}
```

or if you want to use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = ["a:2", "b:5", "c:7", "a:8"]

dd = defaultdict(list)

for item in list1:
    key, value = item.split(":")
    dd[key].append(value)

print(dd)
```

output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': ['2', '8'], 'b': ['5'], 'c': ['7']})
```

Comment: Thanks Errol! I truly appreciate your help.